# Spring Data UpdateTimestamp for specific column

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I use Spring Boot and Spring Data for my project. In one of the tables I have a column called "itemStatus". Now I want to add another column with a timeStamp something like "itemStatus_LastModifiedDate" to keep the date of the latest update to the itemStatus column.

Is there a way to do this cleanly with the help of some annotations like:

```
@LastModifiedDate
@UpdateTimestamp
private Date itemStatusLastModifiedDate
```

Because as far I know these above only work when there is an update to the entity and not to a specific column.

Answer (score 0):

1 You can not use annotation @UpdateTimestamp to track the update of a single field.

2 You can do a custom update using @SqlUpdate annotation with a custom update query.
Something like this (I didn't check this code)

```
@SqlUpdate(update item set item_status = :itemStatus, itemStatusModDate = case when (item_status = :itemStatus) then sysdate() else item_status_mod_date where id = :id)
public class Item {

  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private String itemStatus;

  private Date itemStatusModDate;
..................................................
}
```